# iOS 13 - Custom back button without text Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, back, ios13

In my app, I have a custom icon for going back to previous `ViewController`.
It was working perfectly, but with iOS 13, the icon is misplaced.

The fun fact is that I still have to click on the left (where the back icon used to be, and in other words, on the blank space) to go back to previous `ViewController`.

Do you have any idea why?

Here is the code I use to customize the back button.

```
var back = UIImage(named: "backButton")
back = back?.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -50, 0, 50))
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = back?.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -50, 0, 50))

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = back?.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -50, 0, 50))

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: nil, action: nil)

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
```

And this is a screenshot of the back icon, not on the left anymore:
[image]

Comment: You seem to use a lot of `UIEdgeInsetsMake`, maybe try other values?

Comment: show this method too    withAlignmentRectInsets

Comment: Did you ever fix this @KevinB?

Answer (score 0):

Using `UIBarButtonItem` with `customView` suits well to your situation. By creating an instance of `UIButton` gives you command over choosing image and title both, besides custom selector can also be passed to handle button events.

Here is sample code:

```
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "YOUR IMAGE NAME"), for: .normal)
button.setTitle("TITLE IF ANY", for: .normal)
button.sizeToFit()
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backBtnPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

let leftBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
leftBtn.style = .plain
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBtn

@objc func backBtnPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("BackBtnPressed")
}
```